# Hardhat.config.ts throwing "Cannot use import statement outside a module" for NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, blockchain, hardhat

I want to use hardhat with nestjs and deploy contracts through HRE

- If I use require statements, the plugins don't work
- If I use import statements, it gives can't use import outside module

Script to deploy contract

```
const tokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Token')
const token = await tokenFactory.deploy(args)
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  },
  "include": ["/**/*.ts", "hardhat.config.js"],
  "files": ["hardhat.config.js"]
}
```

Hardhat.config.ts

```
require('hardhat')

require('hardhat-deploy')
require('hardhat-deploy-ethers')
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')

require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers')

require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.15',
  
  ---- NETWORKS SECTION ----

  paths: {
    sources: 'tokens'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to solve it is by having this structure:

```
project/
  solidity/
    contracts/
    test/
    scripts/
    ...
    hardhat.config.ts
  src/
  dist/
  artifacts/
  ...
  hardhat.config.js
```

Basically you need to configure the Solidity folder with

```
npm i --save-dev hardhat
npx hardhat
```

with the typescript template.

Then in the hardhat.config.ts have the artifacts path to be in the parent folder like so

```
paths: { artifacts: '../artifacts' }
```

Then in the project folder install hardhat and hardhat-toolbox

```
npm i --save-dev hardhat
npm i --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
```

And configure it without a template by choosing

```
Create an empty hardhat.config.js
```

Then set it to the default js config

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17"
};
```

Comment: It's not working as expected, I can't import ethers and also throwing can't import outside module